# Alert center element window (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display an alert when a particular element in the html document is in the center of the window, how to do this using jquery? 
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post what you have so far?

Comment: By center, do you mean the element is below the fold and the user has scrolled down?

Comment: And also define "center."  Vertical?  Horizontal?  Both?  Is there an allowance for error, or tolerance?  How much?  And so on...

Comment: When I said the center, meant vertically centered in the window will display the alert when the scroll this element to align,

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the code so I will just show you some stuff to get you started.

You could start by getting the window width and height:

`$(window).width()`

`$(window).height()`

When you have those you can use some maths to find the center point.

Heres some pseudo code:

```
centerX = windowWidth - (elementWidth / 2)
centerY = windowHeight - (elementHeight / 2)
```

That would give you the center point of the screen.

This would just be the visible viewport though. If you wanted the center of the entire document you could use:

`$(document).height()`

Comment: Carl Markham, thanks, but the element is going somewhere in the html document, I rolling the page and when this element to vertically align the center of the screen, I want to display an alert.